# Update Panel PostBackTrigger, Update Progress not displaying

Tags: asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have an update panel and  update progress with a  PostBackTrigger Event. But update progress is not showing when i am clicking on the button. please find the below sample code

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatepanelDropDownTaskType" CssClass="Token-setup-popup" DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="loading" class="loading">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgBusyIndicator" ImageUrl="~/images/busy-indicator.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelDropDownTaskType" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>     
            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV"  CssClass="button" CausesValidation="true" onclick="btnExport_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"/></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My code behind

```
HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        Response.ContentType = FileType;
        Response.Write(content);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Refer this link for the solution http://forums.asp.net/t/1101546.aspx?Update+Progress+show+on+Ajax+Full+Postback+Trigger

Comment: Finally i got an answer for this. i will post the updated code here in few minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i acheived this task, with the help of iframe and endrequestHandler of sys.webforms. i explained clearly in my blog , please find the link http://bhuvanram.wordpress.com/. The Complete method has to be called in Iframe instead of calling in the same page

Answer (score 6):

Well Your code is Okay. Problem is with your `Triggers` which you are using in `UpdatePanel`.

Microsoft says

> The `UpdateProgress` control renders a `<div>` element that is
>   displayed or hidden depending on whether an associated `UpdatePanel`
>   control has caused an **`asynchronous` postback**. For **initial page
>   rendering and for `synchronous` postbacks**, the `UpdateProgress`
>   control is not displayed.

See more details on **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx)**

So you are using `PostBackTrigger` in your `UpdatePanel` which will cause a `synchronous` postback and `UpdateProgress` will not show up .

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
    // Incorrect
</Triggers>
```

Change it to

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
    // Correct
</Triggers>
```

And this will show up your `UpdateProgress` and will work as you are expecting.

As you have mentioned in your comments you are performing downloading as well on your `Grid`. Same way you could register your `Button` with `ScriptManager`. This will register your button and will aware of download button while `asynchronous` postbacks.

```
 protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {    
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         Button btnExport = e.item.FindControl("btnExport") as Button;
         if (btnExport != null)
         {
             ((ScriptManager)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ID of your Script manager")).RegisterPostBackControl(downloadDocColumn);
             // In Above line i assumed Script Manager is placed on Your master page.
         }
     }
  }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Mayank, thank you for the description. I updated my questing by including the code behind. So because of the HttpResponse i need to do the full post back. So if i use Async Post back my export to excel is not working... :(

Comment: i am getting as exception as "Control with ID 'btnExport' cannot be registered through both RegisterAsyncPostBackControl and RegisterPostBackControl. This can happen if you have conflicting triggers associated with the target control."

Comment: Could you please try adding `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` on `btnExport` click...Let me know if it works..

Comment: I tried same with Jqeury, but i am getting an error as the call to server is failed

Comment: and according toy your code behind, you are registering the button as postbackcontrol, but here i already defined the postbacktrigger in the updatepanel design. so do you think your code behind resolves the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an "Ajaxable Panel" (term explained in blog post) that may be helpful in your scenario.

http://leftyftw.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/an-ajaxable-panel/

It was geared towards SharePoint, but is perfectly applicable here.

Comment: Hi Jamie Torres. Actually i need show the progress, when the user clicks on Export to excel button. Export to excel doesnt works in update panel. so i moved the button outside of UpdatePanel, but now i am stucked that. how do i show the update progress for complete postback button..

Comment: The `AjaxablePanel` does how progress while the backend is processing the request.  However, if your code cannot utilize an UpdatePanel (why is that?), you will have to create a custom solution since full postbacks effectively your ability to report back status.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below to your web.config file under system.web

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional"/>
```

It may fix your problem if code is perfect.
Vote as answer if it fix your issue.